# Unable to select Report Excel xls file (Error:External table is not in the expected format)

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

```
Try
    Dim path As String = String.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + CCAM_Browe.FileName)))
    CCAM_Browe.PostedFile.SaveAs(path)
    Using OleDBcon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended properties=Excel 12.0;")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", OleDBcon)
            Using objAdapterr1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                OleDBcon.Open()
                Dim dr As DbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Dim con_str As String = "Data Source=GFCKUL-A0027716\;Initial Catalog=Inbound_VSM;Integrated Security=True"
                Using bulkInsert As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con_str)
                    bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "test"
                    bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr)
                End Using
                OleDBcon.Close()
                lblMsg.Text = "Upload Successful"
                File.Delete(Convert.ToString(CCAM_Browe.PostedFile.FileName))

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    lblMsg.Text = "Upload Unsuccessful, Please contact Administrator to assist"
End Try
```

The error occur at line `OleDBcon.open()`. I'm fed up with this problem , i currently installed **`Microsoft Excel 2013 32-bit`** .

This code work fine with if it's not Report Excel file.

Please help me! Thanks!